# Column match but print value of other column in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two CSV files, examples mentioned below

```
File 1
A,B
a1,21
b1,31
c1,2
```

```
File 2
A,B
a1,2
d1,4
c2,23
```

```
Require output (a tab separated file)

A    file_1    file_2
a1   21        2
b1   31        NA
c1   2         NA
d1   NA        4
c2   NA        23
```

I am new to python, can anyone help how to solve this problem

Comment: Please post the code you have attempted for this.

Comment: If you have no idea where to start, look into [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html#min) for reading the files as dataframe and combine the dataframe together.

Comment: There is a python module called Pandas that does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, look into the pandas module. If you are using python to work with structured data, this is a module you would benefit from becoming familiar with. The function you'll likely want to use is *join* which works similarly to an SQL join.

```
import pandas as pd
file1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv',index_col='A')
file2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv',index_col='A')

output = file1.join(file2,how='outer',lsuffix='_file_1', rsuffix='_file_2')
output.to_csv('joined_files.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='A', how='outer')
```